# Install ns-2.34 on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos

I've bern struggling to install `ns-2.34` on my just uppgraded Mac with ML.
This is what I get

```
-L/Users/bcaceiro/desktop/DEI/IRC/ns-allinone-2.34/tcl8.4.18/unix -ltcl8.4  -framework CoreFoundation -lX11   -sectcreate __TEXT __info_plist Wish-Info.plist  -o wish
ld: library not found for -lX11
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [wish] Error 1
tk8.4.18 make failed! Exiting ...
```

And, I have Xcode installed, with the command line tools , all installed, but can't seem to get this working.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I see that the message contains a reference to X11, X11 is not installed by default in Mountain Lion. The first invocation of /Applications/Utilities/X11.app will prompt you to find the current Apple Knowledge Base Article for installing X11.

Download and install the latest version of XQuartx (2.7.3 at time of writing) from http://xquartz.macosforge.org

Comment: I have already did that . However the error remains the same . I believe that the install file that comes with the ns folder, should be rearranged , but I don't know